# How to stop Github Actions step when functional tests failed (using Codeception)

Tags: php, github, functional-testing, codeception, github-actions

I'm new with Github Actions and I try to make some continuous integration with functional tests.

I use Codeception and my workflow run perfectly, but when some tests fail the step is written as success. Github don't stop the action and continue to run the nexts steps.

**Here is my workflow yml file :**

```
name: Run codeception tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [ feature/functional-tests/codeception ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

    # —— Setup Github Actions  —————————————————————————————————————————————
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # —— Setup PHP Version 7.3  —————————————————————————————————————————————
    - name: Setup PHP environment
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@master
      with:
        php-version: '7.3'

    # —— Setup Docker Environment  ————————————————————————————————————————————— 
    - name: Build containers
      run: docker-compose build

    - name: Start all container
      run: docker-compose up -d

    - name: Execute www container
      run: docker exec -t my_container developer

    - name: Create parameter file
      run: cp app/config/parameters.yml.dist app/config/parameters.yml

    # —— Composer ‍️ —————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    - name: Install dependancies
      run: composer install

    # —— Check Requirements  —————————————————————————————————————————————
    - name: Check PHP version
      run: php --version

    # —— Setup Database  —————————————————————————————————————————————
    - name: Create database
      run: docker exec -t mysql_container mysql -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root --password=**** -e "CREATE DATABASE functional_tests"

    - name: Copy database
      run: cat tests/_data/test.sql | docker exec -i mysql_container mysql -u root --password=**** functional_tests

    - name: Switch database
      run: docker exec -t php /var/www/bin/console app:dev:marketplace:switch functional_tests

    - name: Execute migrations
      run: docker exec -t php /var/www/bin/console --no-interaction doctrine:migrations:migrate

    - name: Populate database
      run: docker exec -t my_container php /var/www/bin/console fos:elastica:populate

    # —— Generate Assets  ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    - name: Install assets
      run: |
        docker exec -t my_container php /var/www/bin/console assets:install
        docker exec -t my_container php /var/www/bin/console assetic:dump

    # —— Tests ✅ ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
    - name: Run functional tests
      run: docker exec -t my_container php codeception:functional

    - name: Run Unit Tests
      run: php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c app/
```

**And here is the logs of the action step :**

[Github Action log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF3Sk.png)

Anyone know why the step don't faile and how to throw an error ?

Comment: Yes the command `codeception:functional` was returning an exit code 0. I should have looked better ! Thank you so much, it works now ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `codeception:functional` set an exit code = 0 even though an error occured. `docker exec` passes the exit code of the process through. GitHub Actions fails the step if a command returns with an exit code != 0.