# How to fail job in a github-actions when running tests are skipped/failed

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm trying to use GitHub Actions for CI testing but my job isn't failed if running test are skipped or failed. it shows the pass status of the test job

GithubAction Workflow[image]

Could anyone please give any suggestion that would really help

Workflow.yml:

name: Android build

on: push

```
jobs:

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v1


      - name: Set Up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Clean
        run: ./gradlew clean

      - name: Compile
        run: ./gradlew compileDebugSources

      - name: Unit Tests
        run: ./gradlew test

      - name: Build Project
        run: ./gradlew assembleRelease

      - name: Sign Apk
        id: sign
        uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
        with:
          releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/apk/release
          signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.SIGNING_KEY }}
          alias: ${{ secrets.ALIAS }}
          keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD }}
          keyPassword: ${{ secrets.KEY_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build Analysis
        run: ./gradlew lint

      - name: Artifact Build report
        if: ${{ always() }}
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: CICDArtifacts
          path: app/build/reports

      - name: Artifacts APK
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: CICDArtifacts
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk

      - name: upload app to pCloudy
        env:
          PCLOUDY_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.PCLOUDY_USERNAME }}
          PCLOUDY_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.PCLOUDY_ACCESS_KEY }}
        run: |
            echo "install cURL"
            sudo apt install curl
            echo "Verify install of curl on Ubuntu"
            curl --version
            echo "upload apk"
            curl -X POST -F "file=@/home/runner/work/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned-signed.apk" -F "source_type=raw" -F "token=t9xm" -F "filter=all" https://device.pcloudy.com/api/upload_file
  test:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest # the machine type
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2 #checkout the code
        with:
          repository: testrepo     
      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Run tests on pCloudy  
        id: pCloudy
        run: mvn clean test
        continue-on-error: false
      - name: Check on failures
        if: steps.pCloudy.outputs.status == 'failure'
        run: exit 1
```

this is the workflow.yml file

Comment: Can you add your github workflow config?

Comment: Probably the command you're executing to run your tests returns an exit code = 0 even though at least one test is failing (see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303997/how-to-stop-github-actions-step-when-functional-tests-failed-using-codeception/).

Comment: @MadhuBhat I have added workflow file, please do have a look

Comment: @riQQ  could you please tell me how to exit code !=0 ; i have been using maven project

Comment: Could you please add your complete workflow config to your question and not only an excerpt

Comment: No I can't this is something which I can't share it online

Comment: Do you have `continue-on-error` set on the step?

Comment: No I havn't added continue-on-error set on the step. How does it help

Comment: @riQQ added workflow file for your refence please do have a look

Comment: I dunno if it helps but in gradle there's a `--fail-fast` option which might suffice for your use case. But as the name says it aborts after the first failing test and not after the whole run.

Comment: got the solution.  updating pom.xml by using      <buildSuccessOnTestFailure>false</buildSuccessOnTestFailure>